# UIApplicationState of app is inactive after following interactive push notification when app is closed

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications, uiapplication

App is not running.  Interactive push notification comes in.  User taps a button on it.  App is launched, notification action is handled, but app state is still inactive.  Even when I background/foreground the app, it's still inactive.  If I follow the notification directly (tapping the notification, not the interactive button) from the same notification, the app gets launched and is in active state.  Why doesn't it always go to active state?

Answer (score 0):

Have some thoughts on this.

First of all, it's not a given that a notification will result in a user opening up the app. 
Second, there are notification callbacks in the delegate. Is it possible to manually set the application state?

If not, and I don't want to jump to conclusions, but this sounds like it may be a bug, and you may want to file a radar.

Although, you may be able to work around it. Look at those delegate methods.